# Where's the key to the cells on level 2?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I'm on level two now, and I went past the part where it says "Shelter Left; Cells Right". I went into the shelter, and now I'm in the cells, but I don't see how to open them. I see a keyhole, but I can't find a key. I've looked all over the level, but I don't know how to open any of the cells.

[image: The keyhole and exiting door]

[image: My current map location]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually had a huge problem with this.

But, I finally figured it out! If you backtrack to the hallway, you'll see a cell with some arrows, and a pile of cloth on the ground. **You can actually click on the cloth through the cell door to pick it up.**

Underneath this pile of cloth (a vest), you will find the key!

[Map location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJw8n.jpg)

[Picture of the cell originally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOWDk.jpg)

[Key!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN0RP.jpg)

Comment: I've been searching for an hour! grumble grumble -_-

Comment: Just as well it was not a brown key on a brown background :(